# Tables side by side won't work in Outlook

Tags: css, html-table, outlook, html-email

I have created two tables that sit side by side for an email newsletter but when viewed in Outlook the second table goes under the first.

Here is the [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M3ae2/).

HTML:

```
<div id="container">

<table id="table1">
    <tr>
        <th colspan="2">&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td height="106" colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td height="155">&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td height="114">&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table id="table2">
    <tr>
        <th colspan="2">&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td height="236">&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td height="118">&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
#table1, #table2 {
    border: 1px solid black;
    float: left;
    width: 350px;
}
#table2 {
    float: right
}
#container {
    width: 700px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: You can nest both tables within two cells of a father table

Comment: I would try adding `margin:0` to the tables and also try out what happens if you set the `border:0px;` as long as you count on exact pixels.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can nest both tables within two cells of a father table.

```
<table class="father">
  <tr>
    <td>
        <table>...</table>
    </td>
    <td>
        <table>...</table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I've changed my code around and gone with your idea. I think it's most suited to what I am after and should cause the least problems. Thanks @Harsh

Comment: Glad to help :)
Also, keep in mind that if you are targeting mail clients, inline your css into element's style attribute.

Comment: I've been trying for hours with relative positioning, in-line, etc. and this was the only thing that worked!! thanks man

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
table{table-layout: fixed;}
```

Or you have wrapped the both table in a div that is `container`. Define the width of this like `#container{width: 1200px;}`.

**as per your comment**

The width of container is defined only 700 pixels that is less than the width of both table which is causing to go below the first table. So, increase the width of `#container` which covers both table's width.

Comment: `table{table-layout: fixed;}` hasn't worked. And i'm unsure about defining the `container` width as I already have `#container{width:700px;margin:0 auto;}`

Comment: I have increased the width by 10px but It hasn't affected anything. How is the DIV not wide enough when it's 700px and both tables are 350px? surely that's the exact width?